# How do I implement temporal leaderbords with Redis?

Tags: redis

With Redis, it's trivial to implement a scoreboard with sorted sets, but I'm unsure of how to implement scoreboards with a rolling temporal window (ie. 30/60/90 day windows).

Since sorted set entries don't have any temporal component, what's the best way to implement time-based leaderboards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two general approaches (i.e. details need to be filled in ;) that you can mull over:

1) Use the fractional nature of Redis' ZSETs (ordered sets) to store both the time and the user's (?) score (e.g. the integer part can be a timestamp and the fraction the score). A range on the timestamp part can give you temporal effects but for ordering you'd have to reset the "LSB"s of the epoch value.

2) Use different leadboards, one for each rolling window, and periodically or upon touching the DB maintain them.

The 1st approach is simpler but you could run into extreme cases (e.g. limits of a the float datatype, huge ZSETs...), so you should consider partitioning your leaderboards in advance if that's an issue.

Edit - more examples:
Let's assume your leaderboard's key is `k` and that you're tracking term1. Naively, when there's a hit on term1, you'll do:

```
ZADD k <epoch> <epoch>:term1
```

This will give you 1sec resolution per term hit but you need more and there's no point in keeping count this way. So, let's assume that `<epoch*>` is always 12AM. Instead of counting each term hit independently, aggregate it like so:

```
escore = ZSCORE k:<epoch*> term1
if (escore == nil):
    escore = 0

ZADD k:<epoch*> escore+1 term1
```

To aggregate in rolling window, e.g. 30 days, decide that `k:<epoch*>:30d` is a rollup of all days between `<epoch*>` and `<epoch*>`-30 days. So with every `term1` hit, you'll do something like:

```
# initialize today's rolling window if it doesn't exist
if not(EXISTS k:<epoch*>:30d):
    ZUNIONSTORE k:<epoch*>:30d 29 k:<epoch*>-1d ... k:<epoch*>-29d AGGREGATE SUM

rscore = ZSCORE k:<epoch*>:30d term1
if (rscore == nil):
    rscore = 0

ZADD k:<epoch*>:30d rscore+1 term1
```

That's actually what I meant with the 2nd approach, so yeah you'll be keeping 30 keys (just remember to delete/expire them once they're not needed anymore).

The 1st approach would consist of using a single k ZSET for everything. Assuming that your term counts can go up to 10000, consider the following pseudo that does per term counts and rollups:

```
escore = ZSCORE k <epoch*>:term1
rscore = ZSCORE k <epoch*>:30d:term1
if (escore == nil):
    escore = <epoch*>

if (rscore == nil):
    rscore = <epoch*>
    for (i=1; i++; i<30):
        rscore += fractional(ZSCORE k <epoch* - i*days>:term1)

ZADD k escore+1/10000 <epoch*> + ':term1'
ZADD k rscore+1/10000 <epoch*> + ':30d:term1'
```

This design uses a single `k` to store all rollups, where the score's integer part is the epoch (allowing you to do ranges) and the fractional part is the counter (% 10000).

Comment: I'm not following with (1). Could you provide an example of the ZINCRBY and ZRANGEBYSCORE (if those are the commands you'd use?)

With (2), if I wanted to show, for example, "most used search terms in the last 30 days," would I need 30 leaderboards? I'd ZINCRBY into all 30 when processing a search term in my app, then read from the appropriate set (the oldest)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Very helpful to a beginner like me. Thanks for taking the time to be so detailed!

Comment: One question -- if a new set is created daily using ZUNIONSTORE w/ AGGREGATE SUM, and then that set is used in the next day's ZUNIONSTORE creation process, then won't we be artificially increasing scores? It doesn't seem like the output of ZUNIONSTORE should be used in another ZUNIONSTORE, or else counts from 30+ days ago will never "fall off," since they'll always be carried over. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, of course - I guess my pseudo-compiler needs an upgrade. Will edit the answer :)